# How to count online users on a website

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [script to tell me who, and how many users, are online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568835/script-to-tell-me-who-and-how-many-users-are-online)
>   [Best way to keep track of current online users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822921/best-way-to-keep-track-of-current-online-users)

How should I count the people online on a PHP website at a given time, if they don't have to be logged-in?

Comment: And many others: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=users+online

Comment: has anyone noticed that asking these repeated questions actually help people out? In that it gathers all related responses in one place making searches easier :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a cookie to identify unique users, and then just keep track of the last time accessed a PHP page. Then come up with a timeout mechanism - for example, if they have not accessed a page in 15 minutes then they are removed from the count.

Answer (score 0):

Treat them as anonymous user. Assign a random user ID in a cookie. In your UI, show all the anonymous users as "Guest".

Answer (score 0):

Just write an IP addresses along with timestamp into a file.  On a page load read this file, delete all records, say, 3 minutes older, add current IP and count the lines, write the file back. A lock on this file would be nice.

That's all. All other methods listed here are just overpowered for such a trifling thing, inaccurate by design, no matter the method you use.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/PHP/The-Quickest-Way-To-Count-Users-Online-With-PHP/1/

I would say to google, you can a lot of scripts and articles related to your query.

Comment: Strange... that's how most people got to THIS page to begin with.