# How to learn online user number in PHP?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I'm developing a forum and I need to count the number of online persons.

According to old questions which are related to it, they says the `count()` function should be used.

But the `count()` function counts just specific user's session variables.
I mean in codeigniter, `count($_SESSION['user'])` gives number `2` and this number points to `$_SESSION['user']['name']` and `$_SESSION['user']['group']`.

So every user sees number `2` in their screen as online person number. But I need to number of allocated `$_SESSION['user']` variable in the server, not number of specific session variable's sub variables. What is the solution? How can I detect number of online persons?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843989/how-to-count-online-users-on-a-website

Answer (score 3):

In this case, you want to have a database, preferably `MySQL` and update the `users` table with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` whenever the user reloads the page or does anything on the site.

Afterwards, if you want to obtain current users online, you can do

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE last_activity > NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE;
```