# I want to query ci_sessions table to check how many users are online

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am using storing sessions and can anyone help me with querying the
`ci_sessions table` i have tried querying to check time stamps but that doesn't give actually nothing.

Below is what gets generated when user is logged in in data column.

```
__ci_last_regenerate|i:1526050456;user_id|s:2:"37";username|s:12:"shkhussain12";logged_in|b:1;
```

---

and this is  generated when user is logged out

```
__ci_last_regenerate|i:1526050456;
```

Comment: Might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36888422/how-to-learn-online-user-number-in-php